# I built an OpenCV project in C++ visual studio 2019 using static library, but still needs dll file at the run time

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, visual-studio-2019, static-libraries

I built an OpenCV project in C++ visual studio 2019 using static library:
I made path to the lib file and also set Runtime Library (in project properties--> C\C++--> code generation) as Multi-Threaded/MT. Project is in Release mode.
Also I made similar to the following video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=or1dAmUO8k0

Comment: The static library you linked to was probably an import library. These also have a .lib extension and are used alongside dlls

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my program ask for OpencV's .dll even though I link statically against its .lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592708/why-does-my-program-ask-for-opencvs-dll-even-though-i-link-statically-against)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you also need to set these dlls into system environment variables. The dlls are from [OpenCVInstallation]\build\x64\vc15\bin and OpenCVInstallation\build\bin, which is like:
[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWiOA.jpg)