# How to build opencv and own program into dll

Tags: c++, opencv, dll

I've developed a little, OpenCV dependent program in C++ with VS2015.

I would like to save it into a single *.dll file with OpenCV included in it so that I could hand it to someone who doesn't have OpenCV on their machine.

I've searched it but there's only 1 way like copy the OpenCV's *.dll-s into my project which is not that satisfying.

Program could be like:

```
#define dll_API __declspec(dllimport)
etc..

class dll_API ocr
public
{
  recognize(frame, int, int, ...);
  blur(frame, int, int, ..);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583172/opencv-as-a-static-library-cmake-options

Answer (score 1):

If you want to embed that library into your application, you should:

- Compile OpenCV as a static library (`.lib`): See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583172/opencv-as-a-static-library-cmake-options)
- Compile your dynamic library (`.dll`) against OpenCV's static library
- Ship your dynamic library as a single file