# Cannot build Opencv as static libraries

Tags: opencv, build, static

I am building opencv 4.6.0 on ubuntu. I included -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF but still get "*.so" dynamic libraries only. I am expecting "*.a" static libraries.

Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-build-static-libraries/9935

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583172/opencv-as-a-static-library-cmake-options). It looks like you are having an **extra space**. It should be `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` instead of `-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`.